# Submit button used out of the form

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, html-table

Can I use submit button out of the form and still process the form action on clicking submit button?  Below is the code. I am new to programming. Please help me.

```
<body>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
<form action="" method="get" name="myform">
  <table width="200" border="1" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td><label for="name"></label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>email</td>
      <td><label for="email"></label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Group</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="IT" id="IT" />
        IT 
          <input type="checkbox" name="ECE" id="ECE" />
        <label for="ECE"></label>
        ECE
        <input type="checkbox" name="Mech" id="Mech" />
        <label for="Mech"></label>
        Mech</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hobbies</td>
      <td><label for="hobbies"></label>
      <input type="text" name="hobbies" id="hobbies" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not just put the button inside the form? Can you tell us what your goal is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it either by using HTML5, pure JavaScript or jQuery:

**Using JavaScript:**

```
<form action="" method="get" id="theForm">
// Form here
</form>

<input type="submit" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" />
```

**Using jQuery:**

```
<form action="" method="get" id="theForm">
// Form here
</form>

<input type="submit" id="submitTheForm" />

$('#submitTheForm').click(function(){
    $('#theForm').submit();
});
```

**Using CSS (if if you only want it outside the form for aesthetic reasons):**

A better option might be to leave your submit inside the form, and position it elsewhere using CSS (if that's the reason you wanted it outside the form).

**Using HTML5:**

Finally, you should look into using HTML5's [form attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp). Note that they are supported in all major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE10) but not in older versions of IE (IE9, IE8 etc). This should also work:

```
<form id="something" method="post"> 
<input type="text"/> 
</form> 

<input type="submit" form="something">
```

Comment: Just curious: what about new HTML5 attribute "form". I.E. <form id="something" method="post">
    <input type="text"/>
</form>

<input type="submit" form="something">

I know that will work on modern browsers, but I've never tested with submit button outside of form.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović I don't know if that's supported in IE yet or?

Comment: Maybe on IE10, but OP not mentioned browser support, so maybe is good to update answer (well, this IS another way to do that, so...). And ofcourse, note about browser support.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović Sure is, I'll update that in the answer. I long for the day when IE9 and before are refined to history :D

Comment: Thanks i gave +1 for your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this using jQuery

```
<a href="#" id="submit-form">Submit</a>
<form id="someid">

</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#submit-form").click(function(){
$("#someid").trigger("submit");
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Using JQuery :

```
<form action="" method="get" name="myform" id="myform">
...
</form>

<input type="button" id="submitform" value="click me to submit the form" />

$('#submitform').click(function(){
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use some javascript to achieve this. Here's an example

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.forms['myform'].submit()" value="Submit" />
```